How to resolve npm error "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'peer')"
Was trying to add shadcn.ui to my project, however I got this error with npm.
PS C:\Users\***\react-project\frontend> npx shadcn@latest init
npm ERR! Cannot set properties of null (setting 'peer')

Tried this link and this but the same error still persisted.
